# Почему VS Code не видит "Git Bash"?

Tags: консоль, visual-studio-code, git-bash

Появилась необходимость сделать **Git Bash** терминалом **по умолчанию**, но не напрямую задавая путь на `bash.exe` в `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows":`, а через **интерфейс VS Code**:

[image: Выбор профиля]

т.е. выбрать **"Git Bash" профиль** в этом подменю или же задать его **профилем по умолчанию**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но VS Code не видит **профиль "Git Bash"**

`settings.json`:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Git Bash": {
        //"source": "Git Bash",
        "icon": "terminal-bash",
        "path": "D:\\Web\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
    },
    "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    }
}
```

Comment: `bash.exe` это не то же самое что `Git Bash` ищите `git-bash.exe` путь можете посмотреть по свойствам ярлыка в меню

Comment: @DaniilLoban Да, но в данном случае необходим именно bash.exe, а не git-bash.exe или я где-то ошибаюсь? Мне же необходимо запускать терминал **В** VS Code, а не **ВНЕ**, а если указать путь на  git-bash.exe, то результат будет не тот, что мне необходим. Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: `D:\\Web\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe` есть этот файл?

Comment: @DaniilLoban Конечно есть, в первую очередь проверил)

Comment: Пока проверить не могу но возможно `path` должно быть массивом?

Comment: похоже ошибка не воспроизводится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Проблема найдена.**

VS Code почему-то не отображает профиль из-за самого названия "Git Bash", а если как-либо изменить само название, например: "GitBash", "Git-Bash" или "Git bash", то все корректно отображает в списке выбора профиля по умолчанию.

```
{
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Git-Bash": {
        //"source": "Git Bash",
        "icon": "terminal-bash",
        "path": "D:\\Web\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
    },
    "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    }
    
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git-Bash"
}
```

[image: Выбор терминала по умолчанию]

[image: меню с профилями терминалов]

Answer (score 1):

- Установил `VS Code`
- Зашел в настройки прописал:

(в пользовательских настройках  `Code > User > settings.json`)

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "Git Bash": {
            "icon": "terminal-bash",
            "path": "C:\\Program files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
        },
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по скриншоту есть параметр `-login` который я не вводил, значит настройки возможно были при установке. Удалил `VS Code`, поставил снова. Да, действительно `bash` есть, возможно потому что это последняя версия 1.71.2.  Но есть один момент, все настройки должны быть заключены целиком в `{ }` иначе они не интерпретируются.

Comment: Последняя версия VS Code и все настройки заключены целиком в `{ }`

Comment: Печально, не понятно тогда в чем дело, а переставить не хотите?

Comment: Что я предлагаю, сделайте копию того что у Вас видно например "PowerShell" просто назовите это иначе например "Shell" и гляньте появится ли в списке, если не появится значит конфиг не читается

Comment: Конфиг читается и проблема найдена. VS Code  почему-то не отображает профиль из-за **самого названия "Git Bash"**, а если как-либо изменить само название, например: "GitBash", "Git-Bash" или "Git bash", то все корректно отображает в списке выбора профиля по умолчанию. Хм, странно, а может ли быть где-то конфиг для игнорирования профилей или что-то в этом роде?

Comment: ну в моем случае это не мешало, хотя я не уверен что и помогало, но я проверял на таком же переименованном клоне и все работало. Думаю вряд ли есть какое-то игнорирование

Comment: @RoNULL думаю Вам стоит добавить ответ, в частности мне интересно глянуть на скриншот как сейчас выглядит выбор по-умолчанию